# VBA: Runtime Error - SetSourceData for Second Pivot Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_Chart' failed

intermittently when I try to run the following script:

```
Sub CreatePiePivot()
'Define worksheets
Set PSheet = Sheets("Tools")
Set DSheet = Sheets("Aggregate")

'Define last data points
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Selects first to last filled row, and first to last filled column for data
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Create pivot cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Moves user to Dashboard
Sheets("Tools").Activate

'Create blank pivot table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("F1"), _
        TableName:="ExcPT1")

'Create blank pivot chart
PSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("$F$2:$H$19"), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Exception")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data
With PSheet.PivotTables("ExcPT1").PivotFields("Exception")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Caption = "Exception Status Count"
    .Function = xlCount
End With

'Hide Not Due
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Exception Status")
    .PivotItems("Not due").Visible = False
End With

'Move bar chart to Dashboard; resize
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Dashboard"

Set ChartWidth = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B26:L49")
With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = ChartWidth.Height
    .Width = ChartWidth.Width
    .Top = ChartWidth.Top
    .Left = ChartWidth.Left
End With

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = False
End With

End Sub
```

This sub is running after another very similar sub that creates a pivot bar chart using a sub connected to a button:

```
Sub CreatePivots()

Call CreateBarPivot
Call CreatePiePivot

End Sub
```

The BarPivot runs perfectly, no problem, every time, and looks almost identical to the PiePivot shown above with the applicable changes to display the appropriate data. If I run those subs separately, it *usually* runs without a problem. I ran-and-deleted the sub and results three times before I got the error. The debug is pointing at this line:

```
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("$F$2:$H$19"), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows
```

...but it looks exactly like the one used by the BarPivot. Since it's not happening exactly every time, but most of the time, I'm not sure where to start on troubleshooting. The documentation I've looked up (which is sparse by the way, or I'm looking in the wrong places) indicates I'm doing this right.

What's causing the error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I've run into this before and IIRC solved it by avoiding the use of `ActiveChart`. Using `ActiveChart` only guarantees you're operating on whatever chart is active (duh), but that's not always the chart you think it is (unless you only have one chart in the whole workbook). [Avoid using Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201705241426107111278), and create an object linked to each specific chart so you'll never have trouble knowing which you're working with.

Comment: This is good advice, PeterT, and I'm glad you brought it up because I felt really uneasy about using so many "Active" items as I was trying to piece this together. This is my first attempt at creating pivot items in VBA so I went with what I could find (which used Active items obviously), so the result is what you see.

At what point/how can I identify each chart as a variable so that I can reference it appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example to illustrate how to avoid using `Select` and `Activate` in your code, plus a few other (hopefully useful) comments.

Always Use Option Explicit - this can't be emphasized enough

This will turn the first few lines of your `Sub` into:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePiePivot()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Set PSheet = thisWB.Sheets("Tools")
    Set DSheet = thisWB.Sheets("Aggregate")
```

Notice that by defining `thisWB`, you're setting up a workbook reference in a single line that, if you ever needed to change workbooks, change that one line and you're done. Also, [this reference](http://analystcave.com/vba-tip-day-activeworkbook-vs-thisworkbook/) can explain why you should use `ThisWorkbook` over `ActiveWorkbook`.

Because some of your issues involve ***assumed*** references (either workbooks or worksheets or charts), the next lines can help show some necessary references that are easy to miss:

```
    'Define last data points
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, DSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Notice here that you have to reference `DSheet` ***inside*** of the `Cells` reference to guarantee that you're referring to the same worksheet. Otherwise VBA could assume that you're referring to the `ActiveSheet`, which may be completely different and give you an incorrect value.

The next few lines become:

```
    'Selects first to last filled row, and first to last filled column for data
    Dim PRange As Range
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol)

    'Create pivot cache
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
                 (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
```

Your next statement in your code is `Sheets("Tools").Activate` which, unless there is a specific reason you want to display that worksheet to the user at this time, is completely unnecessary. If you want the user to view this worksheet when all processing is completed, move this statement to the end of the `Sub`.

Next:

```
    'Create blank pivot table
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
                 (TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("F1"), _
                  TableName:="ExcPT1")
```

The real fix for your error comes next:

```
    'Create blank pivot chart
    Dim PChart As Chart
    Set PChart = PSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    PChart.ChartType = xlPie
    PChart.SetSourceData Source:=PSheet.Range("$F$2:$H$19"), PlotBy:=xlRows
```

Because you're creating an object for the newly added chart, you never have to use `ActiveChart`. It follows the same idea of specifying complete references.

And so on... you can hopefully use these examples to finish out the rest of your code and work through some of the issues you're having. Give it a try.

Comment: This is a huge help, PeterT. I am getting a Type Mismatch error on the Set BPivot = PSheet.Shapes.AddChart line, though. I have a Dim BPivot As Chart line at the top of the sub. I have also added a Dim myWB as Workbook and Set myWB = This Workbook; Set P/DSheet = myWB.Sheets("As applic.").

Comment: You can solve that problem by referring to the documentation for [`Shapes.AddChart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820981(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I don't think I am seeing what you are seeing...?

Comment: Dim BPivot As Shape. That's what the documentation link says (return value: Shape)

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've gone through and done the variable defining, and I'm still getting the original issue from the OP. I am at a loss.

Comment: Create another question and post your new code and ask again. You can even link back to this answer for having cleaned up the references and updated, just to make sure anyone else following this question is up to date.

Comment: Added here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166792/vba-method-setsourcedata-of-object-chart-failed-for-multiple-pivot-charts