# VBA: Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_Chart' failed For Multiple Pivot Charts

Tags: vba, excel

This is part 2 of the previous question:

[VBA: Runtime Error - SetSourceData for Second Pivot Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160540/vba-runtime-error-setsourcedata-for-second-pivot-chart)

After following the (good) advice offered in that thread, I am still having the same problem. The title error is still showing after the second chart attempts to SetSourceData. If I add an On Error Resume Next, then the data gets wonky and unreliable. I'm starting to think it's a problem with the PivotCache, but I've attempted to differentiate the caches with different variable names. This did not solve the issue. Below is the code in it's entirety with some titles/names redacted:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivots()

Call CreateBarPivot
Call CreatePiePivot

End Sub
Sub CreateBarPivot()

Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim PSheet, DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ChartWidth As Range
Dim BPivot As Shape

'Define Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

'Define worksheets
Set PSheet = myWB.Sheets("Tools")
Set DSheet = myWB.Sheets("Aggregate")

'Define last data points
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Selects first to last filled row, and first to last filled column for data
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Create pivot cache
Set PCache = myWB.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Create pivot table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), _
        TableName:="ExcPT")

'Create pivot chart
Set BPivot = PSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    BPivot.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$C$18"), PlotBy:=xlRows
    BPivot.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

With BPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("redacted")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With BPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("redacted")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

With BPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("redacted")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 1
End With

With BPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("redacted")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

'Insert Data
With PSheet.PivotTables("ExcPT").PivotFields("Exception")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Caption = "Exception Status Count"
    .Function = xlCount
End With

'Hide Not Due
With BPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Exception Status")
    .PivotItems("Not due").Visible = False
End With

'Move bar chart to Dashboard; resize
Set ChartWidth = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B2:L25")
With BPivot.Chart.Parent
    .Height = ChartWidth.Height
    .Width = ChartWidth.Width
    .Top = ChartWidth.Top
    .Left = ChartWidth.Left
End With

BPivot.Chart.ChartArea.Select
BPivot.Chart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Dashboard"


End Sub

Sub CreatePiePivot()

Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim PSheet, DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache1 As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ChartWidth As Range
Dim PPivot As Shape

'Define Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

'Define worksheets
Set PSheet = myWB.Sheets("Tools")
Set DSheet = myWB.Sheets("Aggregate")

'Define last data points
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Selects first to last filled row, and first to last filled column for data
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Create pivot cache
Set PCache1 = myWB.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Create pivot table
Set PTable = PCache1.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("F1"), _
        TableName:="ExcPT1")

'Create pivot chart
Set PPivot = PSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    PPivot.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$F$1:$H$18"), PlotBy:=xlRows
    PPivot.Chart.ChartType = xlPie

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

'Insert row
With PPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Exception")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data
With PSheet.PivotTables("ExcPT1").PivotFields("Exception")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Caption = "Exception Status Count"
    .Function = xlCount
End With

'Hide Not Due
With PPivot.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Exception Status")
    .PivotItems("Not due").Visible = False
End With

'Move pie chart to Dashboard; resize
Set ChartWidth = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B26:L49")
With PPivot.Chart.Parent
    .Height = ChartWidth.Height
    .Width = ChartWidth.Width
    .Top = ChartWidth.Top
    .Left = ChartWidth.Left
End With

PPivot.Chart.ChartArea.Select
PPivot.Chart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Dashboard"

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're still leaving lots of unreferenced objects. In `CreateBarPivot` there's  `BPivot.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$C$18"), PlotBy:=xlRows`. What worksheet is the `Range` referring to? Why is A1:C18 hard-coded (should it be the same as `PRange`)? Same questions for your `CreatePiePivot` sub. You only have to use `ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList` once, since it's for the whole workbook -- but you should use `myWB.ShowPivotTableFieldList` instead. Anytime you use `Range`, `Sheets`, `Cells` you should put a reference in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help on this, PeterT. I thought I had changed the source data to include a sheet, but it looks like I've missed it. Since it is a pivot chart using data from a pivot table, should the line be `PPivot.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=PTable, PlotBy:=xlRows`?

Comment: When you look at the [`SetSourceData` method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx), you'll see that it expects a `Range` for the `Source:=` parameter. (I honestly thought it was expecting a `PivotCache`, but no.) So use a sheet-referenced range or a range object variable with the correct area set.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I actually set it to the range set for the table location and it seems to work. I've posted an additional question that seems related here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184383/vba-method-location-of-object-chart-failed-two-pivotcharts?noredirect=1&lq=1 Since your original answer was correct, and it was just my ineptitude that's caused the drawn out fix, I'll mark the original question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, on the Excel 2016 64 bit build.  Solved it using the technique above to create a shape object, instead of a chart object:

```
Dim PChart as shape
Set PChart  = PSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    With PChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xl3DColumn
        .SetSourceData Source:=p.TableRange1, PlotBy:=xlRows
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I solved it by setting to nothing variables holding pivotcache and previously used pivottables (before adding second chart).